# EF 6 и async методы: Заданное приведение является недопустимым

Tags: c#, entity-framework

При использовании любого асинхронного метода получаю исключение:

> "Заданное приведение является недопустимым".

Не асинхронные работают нормально.

Пример:

```
var product =await _dataContext.Products
    .Where(p => p.name == name)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Определение модели:

```
public  class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}  

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int CategoryId  { get; set; }
    public virtual  Category { get; set; }
}
```

Миграция таблиц:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Products",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
        Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        CategoryId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Produtcs", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Products_Categories_CategoryId",
            column: x => x.CategoryId,
            principalTable: "Categories",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Categories",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
            .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
        Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Categories", x => x.Id);
    });
```

Comment: какая база используется?

Comment: @Grundy использую SQlite

Comment: Надо возвращать задачу, и потом уже вызывать ожидание результата.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКидяев, [_FirstOrDefaultAsync_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn220208(v=vs.113).aspx) и возвращает `Task<TSource>`

Comment: Добавь определение типа Products, и определение таблицы Products